# How to switch from block select

Tags: keyboard

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFCO8.png) happen and I'm not sure what key I pressed to set it to this mode. The block select that I'm referring to is where the typing line becomes a block and if I use the arrow keys to move it's position then it hovers ontop of a character instead of between them. This happens in Android studio and Windows randomly so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have pressed the "Insert" key.

Try to repress the "Insert" key to solve the problem.

Hope it`s helpful~

Comment: Yup fixed the issue ! Thanks ! Do you know what key it is for Windows as that "insert Key" seems to work only in Android Studio.

Comment: If the insert key is pressed, then the symbols you add will replace the symbols after where the cursor is located.

Comment: For the keboard layout, you can check it on wikipedia.I am using the 104-key 
 keyboad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout